# Replace jersey-bundle-1.12 with Jsr311-api-1.1.1

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jersey, jsr311

I am trying to replace *Jersey-bundle* with *jsr311-api* but after replacing it on *pom.xml* I am getting *java.lang.CLassNotFoundException com.sun.ws.rs.ext.runtimedelegateimpl*

When I debug a little I found that in *jsr311-api.javax.ws.rs.ext.RunTimeDelegate.findDelegate()* it looks for *javax.ws.rs.ext.RunTimeDelegate* first then looks for *com.sun.ws.rs.ext.runtimedelegateimpl*.
Why it is not able to fund the *javax.ws.rs.ext.RunTimeDelegate* in the first place? and obviously i don't have *runtimedelegateimpl* it is crying about it.
Is it possible to completely replace *jersey-bundle* with *jsr311-api* or I have to keep *jesey-bundle* along with *jsr*?

Comment: just to another imp info : I am getting this error in test which uses the ResponseBuilder, so would it be better to add jersey  dependency for test to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alone *jsr311-api* won't work it needs to have an implementation, so if want to replace *jesrey-bundle*, add *jsr311* and change the *jersey-bundle* scope to *test* because test might use the implementation.